# Beautiful Soup doesn't detect end of td-tag

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am collecting all exam dates of my [faculty](https://www.wiwi.kit.edu/pruefungstermine.php) to keep track of changes etc.

My code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv


data = requests.get('https://www.wiwi.kit.edu/pruefungstermine.php')

soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'lxml')


table = soup.find('tbody').find_all('tr') #finds table with relevant information and returns a list with all entries (is working)

first_row = ('Prüfung', 'Prüfer', 'Datum', 'Zeit/Ort') #header (in German but doesn't matter)

exams = []

for row in table: #looping through every tr
    content = row.find_all('td')
    exam_name = content[0].find('a').text.strip()
    lecturer = content[1].text.strip()
    date = content[2].text.strip()
    time_location = content[3].text.replace('\n', ', ').strip()

    exam = (exam_name, lecturer, date, time_location)
    exams.append(exam)


with open('exams.csv', 'w') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(first_row)
    for row in exams:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

(Could probably only loop once, but that shouldn't be the problem here)

It is working fine to a certain point, but then its not detecting a closing  and the last table entry looks like this:

```
Organisationsmanagement,Lindstädt,13.02.2020,"14.30 - 17.30: Audimax, Neue Chemie</span></td><td class=""dialog""><a href=""/m/ics.php?pruef_id=618550&pIntervall=2020""><img src=""/img/ical_icon.png"" width=""16"" height=""16"" alt=""iCal Eintrag"" /></a></td></tr><tr id=""618551"" title=""&nbsp;""><td><a href=""pruefungstermin.php?func=exam&pruef_id=618551&pIntervall=2020"">Problemlösung, Kommunikation und Leadership (PKL)</a></td><td>Lindstädt</td><td>13.02.2020</td><td>14.30 - 17.30: Audimax, <style=""color:#ff0000;"">Neue Chemie</span></td><td cl ........
```

This is obviously the last table entry, because Beautiful Soup is somehow not detecting the  and the following html code is put in here.

The html code of this entry:

```
<tr id="618552" title="&nbsp;" role="row" class="odd"><td class="sorting_1"><a href="pruefungstermin.php?func=exam&amp;pruef_id=618552&amp;pIntervall=2020">Unternehmensführung und Strategisches Management </a></td><td>Lindstädt</td><td>13.02.2020</td><td>14.30 - 17.30: Audimax, <style="color:#ff0000;">Neue Chemie</style="color:#ff0000;"></td><td class="dialog"><a href="/m/ics.php?pruef_id=618552&amp;pIntervall=2020"><img src="/img/ical_icon.png" width="16" height="16" alt="iCal Eintrag"></a></td></tr>
```

Can anyone say why it is working until this entry?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide either a link to the entire page or include previous row in the data you make available? Can you also please remove the malformed style tags around 'Neue Chemie' and see what that gets you?

Comment: `print(len(exams))` shows 467, which matches the number below the table.

Comment: <style="color:#ff0000;">Neue Chemie</span> is not working. Without span it is working. Link is added.

Comment: That means it is detecting the <tr> correctly. But why is then all the html code in one field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect this is due to the malformed style tags around `Neue Chemie`:

```html
<style="color:#ff0000;">Neue Chemie</style="color:#ff0000;">
```

This is not valid html. Removing the style tags may get you the result you're after. If that works, you can try keeping the style tag but making it a properly-formed tag without any additional information in the closing tag which should always just read `</style>`

After looking at the source, it is indeed malformed HTML:
[image]

Here you have a closing  but no opening span. Instead you have an opening .

Based on the rest of the file it looks like what you wanted was an opening span with a style attribute like:
`<span style="something;">text</span>`

There are quite a few of these that will need to be corrected. You can do this with a search/replace:

search: `<style="color:#ff0000`

replace: `<span style="color:#ff0000`

Comment: I removed the additional info in the closing tag, but its still not working. BS is somehow and not all the time putting " in. Might that be the issue? Because its seen as a string?

Comment: Yes, it certainly could be the issue, but I doubt very much that it's a bs4 issue. Much more likely is that it's more malformed HTML in the original document. Are you able to provide the document? When I see things like the style tag above, I assume there are other errors as well...

Comment: Added the replace command to my script. It is working now. Thank you very much!